# How to define a header for a function to check to maps in C++ using templates

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

What I like is to make a function that can check two maps with key/value pairs where key and value can be any kind of class instances.

What I tried first (it compiles):

```
template<typename T>
bool EqualsMap(int lineNumber, T_String mapText, const T& mapToCheck,     
 T_String expectedText, const T& expectedMap)
{
    ...
}
```

But in this case it can receive any kind of classes (not only maps), and casting might cause a problem.

The following is what I like:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
bool EqualsMap(int lineNumber, T_String mapText, map<T1, T2> mapToCheck,    
 T_String expectedText, map<T1, T2>expectedMap)
{
    ...
}
```

But this does not compile (, or ... expected before <)

How can I implement the header of this function to accept two equally typed maps?

Comment: *"But this does not compile"*, what is the error message?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki (, or ... expected before <)

Comment: *" (, or ... expected before <)"*, this is not a full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be just

```
template<class Key, class Value>
bool EqualsMap(int lineNumber, T_String mapText,
const std::map<Key, Value>& mapToCheck, T_String expectedText,
const std::map<Key, Value>& expectedMap)
{
    ...
}
```

And of course don't forget to `#include <map>`.
If you want to work with any map-like class you can use something like

```
template<template<typename, typename, typename, typename> class Map,
class Key, class Value, class Alloc, class Comp>
bool EqualsMap(int lineNumber, T_String mapText,
const Map<Key, Value, Alloc, Comp>& mapToCheck, T_String expectedText,
const Map<Key, Value, Alloc, Comp>& expectedMap)
{
    ...
}
```

If you can use C++11 it can be something like

```
template<typename Container>
auto EqualsMap(int lineNumber, T_String mapText,
    const Container& mapToCheck, T_String expectedText,
    const Container& expectedMap) -> 
    decltype(std::declval<Container>().begin()->first, bool())
```

Here function will be used only for containers, that value_type has member first (like std::pair).